# How to increase the capacity in Memory Stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, memorystream

I am using MemoryStream to store a report.  But the MemoryStream won't store the report if the size of the report is more than 70000. So I should increase the size of the MemoryStream in that case. How can I increase the size of the MemoryStream?

say for example,

```
mstream=new MemoryStream();
stream.copyTo(mstream); // Here stream contains the report
mstream.position=0;
```

In this case how can I increase the capacity of MemoryStream so that it can store even if the report size is more than 7000.
Please help as I am a beginner in C#.

Comment: MemoryStream could store more than 7000 or 70000 (your reading are not consistent). The limit is available memory for x86 and x64 process (depending how do you execute it). Please describe the problem you have with more details - e.g. more source code, exceptions, and etc.

Comment: @SergeyL, it would be better if you attach a link to, for example, MSDN article about maximum capacity of `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

```
MemoryTributary d = new MemoryTributary();
 int a = d.ReadByte();  
 d.SetLength(10000);  
int b = d.ReadByte();
```