# Increase Memory stream capacity

Tags: c#, reporting-services, memorystream

I am trying to read reports form a SSRS server,
the problem is that my memory stream cant take more than 65536 bytes.

To date i have tried playing around with memory stream but have yet to succeed in setting its capacity BEFORE reading the report itself

```
            GetItemDefinitionResponse reportDefinition = channel.GetItemDefinition(DefinitionRequest);
            MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream(reportDefinition.Definition);
            rdlFile.Load(memstream);
```

The MemoryStream above has to have it capacity increased BEFORE i read the file.

i have tried playing around in my App.config but i dont have a clue where to start to be able to set the byte capacity of the memory stream

Comment: *The MemoryStream above has to have it capacity increased BEFORE i read the file.* Why? And `reportDefinition.Definition` is an what? A byte[] array? An int?

Comment: It may be helpful for you.                                                                                  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850007/how-to-increase-the-capacity-in-memory-stream

Comment: @rene reportDefinition.Definition is indeed a byte[] array, i need to have its capacity increased, because my program keeps bombing when the stream goes over 65536 bytes

Comment: OK, `new MemoryStream(byte[])` produces a non resizable stream. But why would you need it to be resizable in `rdlFile.Load()`? That makes no sense.

Comment: @UmakantDubey - that is an equally nonsensical question.

Comment: @BernardWalters Can you give bigger example of your code, I can't understand what is `GetItemDefinitionResponse` , is it custom object ? Because in MSDN `GetItemDefinition` returning just byte[]

Comment: "because my program keeps bombing when the stream goes over 65536 byte" - provide full error messages and the stack trace.

Comment: It is a garbage-in garbage-out problem, MemoryStream does not have a bug.  There is something wrong with GetItemDefinition(), we can't see it.

Comment: @HansPassant that was actually 100% the case, i logged all the events and got to the conclusion that reportDefinition was the problem...instead of memorystream not having enough capacity...my reportDefinition(Byte[] obtained from ReportingService2010) didnt have a maxbuffersize of more than 65k....all i had to do was set the maxbuffersize of reportingservice2010

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
byte[] bytes = reportDefinition.Definition; 
var ms = new MemoryStream(); 
ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

In this way the `MemoryStream` is resizable.

Probably you should change the position to 0 after writing:

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

but it depends if you want to append new data on the `MemoryStream` (don't set the `Position`) or if you want to simply re-read the data (set the `Position`). `new MemoryStream(reportDefinition.Definition)` has an implicit `Position = 0`.

As a sidenote, the overloads of the constructor of `MemoryStream` that accept a `byte[]` are non-resizable, while the two overloads that don't have a `byte[]` parameter (`MemoryStream()` and `MemoryStream(int)`) are resizable.

Comment: You should reset the `Position` after writing.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen You don't even know how many times I forget to do it and then I'm stumped that the `MemoryStream` is empty :-)

Comment: This may answer the X of a XY-probem but it leaves the (wh)Y wide open.